# save video stream to file without losing performance

Tags: c#, video, kinect

I'm working with kinect and I want to save the video and audio stream do a file (it doesn't matter if I can play it or not, I want to save the raw data).

My question is, if I'm constantly writing to disk (25fps) the computer may lag right? so what I'm trying to do is save to file in an efficient way. I thought of having like a list of images (like 5 seconds) and then write it all to file. What do you think? Is this a correct way?

Or is there another way to do this without losing performance?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing to disk is a low intensitivity task for the CPU, it mostly just uses a memory buffer and some memory bandwidth. However, if you have to access the disk while you are writing to it, you will experience an increased delay.

As for how to do it; I have never worked with video before but I am thinking it is most easily done by using a buffer to hold the captured frames, and then writing from that buffer to the disk.

Saving the frames into arrays of 125 images (5s*25fps) sounds like an inefficient way to buffer the frames. 
As for avoiding losing performance there really is no a way to do this; however I cannot see you losing much performance as the bitrate of the captured video and audio is comparatively low.

Comment: How would you suggest for me to save the frames in an efficient way?

Comment: This thread may be helpful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3dab4b32-2dab-4c29-bd9e-6d36a86da744/video-frame-recording-using-kinect